# EF Core ChangeTracker.DebugView does not show newly added entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an EF Core 5.0.7 model for a legal case. Each case can have a number of `History` entities, each of which records an action on the case. Each `History` entity can have a number of `HistoryFile` entities associated with it.

I'm trying to see what changes have been made when `SaveChangesAsync` is called on the context, so added the following to my `AppDbContext` class...

```cs
public async Task SaveChangesAsync(string message = "") {
  Debug.WriteLine(ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
  await base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The following happens the user uploads a document to the case...

- A new `History` entity is created and saved, so we have the `Id`. This involves one call to `SaveChangesAsync`
- Any associated documents are uploaded to Google Drive, using the new `History` entity's `Id` (which is why we need to save that before the next step), and a web link to the document obtained from Google Drive
- For each document, a `HistoryFile` entity is added to the `History`
- `SaveChangesAsync` is called again to save the `HistoryFile` entities

So, two calls are made to `SaveChangesAsync`, one when the `History` entity is saved (without any files) and one when the `HistoryFile` entities have been added.

However, the `ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView` from the second call doesn't show the newly added `HistoryFile` entities.

The debug from the first call to `SaveChangesAsync` includes the new entity, and shows that it has an empty `HistoryFile` collection, however, debug from the the second call (which is the one where the `HistoryFile` entities were added) doesn't show any files at all. The entry in the long view for the `History` shows (most properties removed for clarity)...

```
History {Id: 189} Unchanged
  Id: 189 PK
  CaseID: 4 FK
  HistoryFiles: [<not found>]
```

...which confuses me, as I don't know why it can't find the `HistoryFile` collection.

Furthermore, there isn't any information in there about the `HistoryFile` entities at all. I expected an entry for each `HistoryFile` entity, just like there is for the other entities.

Anyone any idea why they aren't showing? They are definitely in the context, as they are saved to the database.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe before that you need `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()`?

Comment: *using the new History entity's Id* - yeah, you don't need to. That's how we did stuff back in the days of running SQL ourselves and making sure the parent existed before inserting the child. These days EF does that for us; your history should have a collection of document. If you made a new history and put 10 new documents in the history's rockumentary collection then saved the whole lot EF would do it for you, and in the right order (it would save the history first and then plug its id into all the documents then save them)

Comment: *Anyone any idea why they aren't showing?* - how much micromanaging of the entity graph and change tracking are you doing? I helped on a question last month where related entities were bizarrely disappearing/adding entities was causing others to be deleted. Turned out to be an odd side effect of micromanaging the changes too much. I'd say if you have something acting weird, scaffold your db again(using the same conventions your main project is set for) into a new project and try your save there. If it works, diff the new context and your existing. If no, scaff with defaults,retry, and show us

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm not micromanaging at all, I'm allowing EF Core to do everything. The purpose of this exercise is to have a look at what's change, mainly for dumping to the output window during development. As for the comment about the Id, if you read my question carefully, you'll see that I said I need the Id for when we upload the actual document to Google Drive. I know about object graphs, and would normally do it that way, but in this specific case, I need the new history's Id before I upload the files, and I need them uploaded before I can save the `HistoryFile` entities. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Ah, that was it! If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.